# jQuery Autocomplete Component

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I'm facing a strange issue with autocomplete.

**First issue:**

based on the tutorial found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/13/autocompletion-textbox-in-mvc-using-jquery.aspx), only the first letter of the found items is showing in the list of autocomplete items

Here is an illustration:

**My action at debug time**

*Dummy data returned, always the same regardless of the search pattern just for testing*
[image]

**In the rendered view, this is what happens:**
[image]

The Javascript for autocomplete of this scenario is as follows:

```
$("#Email").autocomplete('@Url.Action("FindEmail", "Administration")',
{
    dataType: 'json',

    parse: function(data) {
        var rows = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            rows[i] = {
                data: data[i].Value,
                value: data[i].Value,
                result: data[i].Value
            };
        }

        return rows;

    },
    width: 300,
    minLength: 3,
    highlight: false,
    multiple: false
        });
```

**Second issue:**

I've changed my code to work with a more comfortable Ajax call for me that depends on Model mapping rather than sending a q and limit parameters as in the previous tutorial, and as I've seen in many other tutorials, but the Ajax call isn't firing, not even giving me an error.

My code for this scenario is based on this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773013/autocomplete-not-firing)

Here is my controller and view code related:

```
        //[HttpPost]
        [SpecializedContextFilter]
        [Authorize]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public JsonResult FindEmail(RegistrationModel model) //Notice the use of model instead of string q and string limit
        {
            //Just a dummy implementation 
            var rez = new List<ValueModel>
            {
                new ValueModel {Description = "atest1@test.com", Value = "atest1@test.com"},
                new ValueModel {Description = "atest2@test.com", Value = "atest2@test.com"},
                new ValueModel {Description = "atest3@test.com", Value = "atest3@test.com"},
                new ValueModel {Description = "atest4@test.com", Value = "atest4@test.com"}

            };

            //var retValue = rez.Select(r => new { email = r.Value }).OrderBy(x => x).Take(10);

            //return Json(retValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return Json(rez, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View JavaScript:

```
    $("#Email").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FindEmail", "Administration")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",

                data: { email: $("#Email").val(), conferenceId: $("#ConferenceId").val() },

                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return { label: item.Value, value: item.Value, id: item.Value };
                    }));
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input[type=hidden]").val(ui.item.id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Firefox console view:

[image]

I've tried a lot of codes for the second scenario, most of them are Stack Overflow answers, but nothing is happening!

I'm my missing anything ?

Note: jQuery plugins are included, Ajax is already working in the same page, so I'm not sure whats the problem

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In the first example, is the dropdownlist showing the first letter of each email address?

Comment: Yes, the first letter of each irem

Comment: So there must be a bug in the javascript for() loop.  Can you debug it in Firebug and see what's happening?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, I tried already 'alert(item.Value) it shows the emails, one by one of course because it's in a loop

Comment: It looks something is taking the first letter of each returned result, agreed? I'm guessing it's the code in your loop: perhaps the 'data[i]'.

Comment: No, I'm sure of that, data[i].Value is a full string, already tested that, tried to take a look at the plugin JavaScript, but I couldn't trace the code

Comment: OK, it took me a while to notice this, but it looks like you are using an old autocomplete plugin: [link](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) Parse is not an option on the current [jquery-ui autocomplete plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) (which I recommend you use instead)

Comment: @JamesS, this sound logical and it explains why scenario 2 is also not working. I will try this later since I've already left work with frustration :D , please add this as an answer that that I can accept it once I try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full working example, see screen grab.

These are the steps that I had take to get the second example working.

**Script-references/Markup/Js**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
<input id="ConferenceId" value="1" />
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="Email">Email: </label>
  <input id="Email">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Email").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FindEmail", "Administration")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",

                data: { email: $("#Email").val(), conferenceId: $("#ConferenceId").val() },

                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Value, value: item.Value, id: item.Value };
                    }));
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("input[type=hidden]").val(ui.item.id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

**Models**

```
    public class RegistrationModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ConferenceId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValueModel
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller Action**

I had to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FindEmail(RegistrationModel model) //Notice the use of model instead of string q and string limit
{
    //Just a dummy implementation 
    var rez = new List<ValueModel>
    {
        new ValueModel {Description = "atest1@test.com", Value = "atest1@test.com"},
        new ValueModel {Description = "atest2@test.com", Value = "atest2@test.com"},
        new ValueModel {Description = "atest3@test.com", Value = "atest3@test.com"},
        new ValueModel {Description = "atest4@test.com", Value = "atest4@test.com"}

    };

    return Json(rez, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Screen grab**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked, the issue as previously said was the use of an older plugin